# Is there any benefit to obsession with making code "look pretty"?

Tags: code-organization

Sometimes I spend ridiculous amount of time (hours) agonising over making code "look pretty". I mean making things look symmetrical. I will actually rapidly scroll through an entire class to see if anything jumps out as not looking "pretty" or "clean".

Am I wasting my time ? Is there any value in this kind of behavior ? Sometimes the functionality or design of the code won't even change, I'll just re-structure it so it looks nicer.

Am I just being totally OCD or is there some benefit hidden in this ?

rust

Answer (score 1):

Answers are going to be opinion-based and subjective, but here's my two cents:

Yes, up to some subjective point of diminishing returns.

Clear, well-formatted and easily understandable code is easier to maintain.  In real-world applications a lot of code persists for years.

Some of the code I work on daily is 15 years old now and parts of it haven't been touched in 5+ years.  Clarity helps to get back up to speed when you're brushing away cobwebs as you read.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not, a cleaner code is easier on the eyes and easily readable, Hence understandable. It is beneficial for others when they try to understand it, or even if you do it again in future.